# Meteor 1.3 React npm conflict

Tags: meteor, reactjs, dependencies

I'm upgrading from Meteor 1.2 to 1.3, and running into a NPM dependency issue with React. When I install the latest version of React (15.0.1), Meteor wants an earlier version (0.14.x). Then, I change my package.json file to 0.14.8, but Meteor wants (15.0.1).

Specifically,

When I install the npm React packages mentioned in the "[Migrating to Meteor 1.3](http://guide.meteor.com/1.3-migration.html)" doc, Meteor wants every package to use an earlier version:

```
W20160412-14:56:42.318(-5)? (STDERR) WARNING: npm peer requirements not installed:
W20160412-14:56:42.318(-5)? (STDERR) - react@15.0.1 installed, react@0.14.x needed
W20160412-14:56:42.319(-5)? (STDERR) - react-dom@15.0.1 installed, react-dom@0.14.x needed
W20160412-14:56:42.319(-5)? (STDERR) - react-addons-transition-group@15.0.1 installed, react-addons-transition-group@0.14.x needed
W20160412-14:56:42.319(-5)? (STDERR) - react-addons-css-transition-group@15.0.1 installed, react-addons-css-transition-group@0.14.x needed
W20160412-14:56:42.319(-5)? (STDERR) - react-addons-linked-state-mixin@15.0.1 installed, react-addons-linked-state-mixin@0.14.x needed
W20160412-14:56:42.319(-5)? (STDERR) - react-addons-create-fragment@15.0.1 installed, react-addons-create-fragment@0.14.x needed
W20160412-14:56:42.319(-5)? (STDERR) - react-addons-update@15.0.1 installed, react-addons-update@0.14.x needed
W20160412-14:56:42.319(-5)? (STDERR) - react-addons-pure-render-mixin@15.0.1 installed, react-addons-pure-render-mixin@0.14.x needed
W20160412-14:56:42.320(-5)? (STDERR) - react-addons-test-utils@15.0.1 installed, react-addons-test-utils@0.14.x needed
W20160412-14:56:42.320(-5)? (STDERR) - react-addons-perf@15.0.1 installed, react-addons-perf@0.14.x needed
```

But, when I go into package.json and downgrade these packages to 0.14.8, I get this error

```
W20160412-17:31:33.167(-5)? (STDERR) WARNING: npm peer requirements not installed:
W20160412-17:31:33.169(-5)? (STDERR) - react@0.14.8 installed, react@15.x needed
W20160412-17:31:33.169(-5)? (STDERR) - react-addons-pure-render-mixin@0.14.8 installed, react-addons-pure-render-mixin@15.x needed
```

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone else ran into this problem, it was caused by the popular ReactLayout package on Atmosphere. (If you use FlowRouter, you almost definitely use ReactLayout.) The Kadira team, which built FlowRouter and ReactLayout, decided not to upgrade ReactLayout for Meteor 1.3.

Instead, they built a new NPM module instead called react-mounter. You need remove ReactLayout and then install react-mounter via npm.

The directions are here https://voice.kadira.io/getting-started-with-meteor-1-3-and-react-15e071e41cd1#.u5quqwvum

Hope this saves you some time!

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instructions here and installed node.js and use the modules from npm and my meteor 1.3 started working again.
https://forums.meteor.com/t/how-to-setup-meteor-1-3beta-react-react-router-via-npm/16013

Comment: Try to be more detailed while answering.